# PHP Image Read Issue

Tags: php, image

I am installing a website on my server, and it seems to have a problem with displaying images. When I enter the image URL, it first gives a 200 response, but then I see the following in the Chrome debugger:

`Invalid` / `(failed)` / `net::ERR_FAILED`

```
Request URL:chrome-extension://invalid/
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Referer:http://tema-arc.co.il/index.php?item=file&action=download/786
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36 OPR/22.0.1471.50 (Edition Campaign 47)
X-Source-Map-Request-From:inspector
```

I have traced the problem to the following function. In the beginning it got the CONTENT-LENGTH wrong, which I fixed, and the following is the updated code.

The file itself exists; when I try to output `$sourceName`, it points to a real image file. The `$size` is currently correct as well. In fact, it even does the dimensions right, as I can "zoom in" in the browser when I go to the image URL, but the image itself is not displayed. Needless to say that I have tried multiple browsers and multiple debuggers, but the Chrome debugger gave the only thing resembling an actual error.

```
function download($fileId)
{
    $db = new Database();
    @clearstatcache();
    $file = $db->table('cms_files')->where(array('fileId' => $fileId))->select();
    $sourceName = Config::get('uploadPath').$file[0]['source'];
    if (!count($file) || !file_exists($sourceName))
    {
        $this->application->setNotFound();
        exit;
    }
    $size = filesize($sourceName);
    $type = $file[0]['type'];
    $name = $file[0]['name'];
    $lastModified = filemtime($sourceName);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.$type);

    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (0 !== strpos($ua, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE ')
        || false !== strpos($ua, 'Opera')) {
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.str_replace('"', '', basename($name)).'"');
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.mb_convert_encoding(str_replace('"', '', basename($name)),"ISO-8859-8", "auto").'"');
    }
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=604800'); // Cache for one week.

    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",$lastModified) . " GMT");

    $ifLastModified = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) ? strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) : FALSE;

    if($ifLastModified !== FALSE && $lastModified <= $ifLastModified)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not modified');
    } 
    else 
    {
        header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($sourceName);      
    } 
    exit;
}
```

Comment: In the end I worked around this by using the original (incorrect) file size with an image file extension—previously the images didn't have a .jpg extension, so Linux automatically thought that each new line was \n while on the previous server (Windows) they were \r\n. This required a remaking of the CMS's upload script to create files with proper extensions but it solved the problem. If someone knows the solution to the original question though it could be helpful to others.